# numer location in group by order by sql

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

suppose i have a table

| number | class |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 10 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 6 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 70 | b |

is there a way in sql to number the location of each row ordered by the number grouped by the class.

so that the wanted answer is

| number | class | placement |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 6 | a | 2 |
| 10 | a | 3 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | b | 2 |
| 70 | b | 3 |

for example:

```
SELECT *,xxxxx
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY class
ORDER by number
```

when the executed table will be as mentioned

Comment: Which dbms you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with row_number():

```
SELECT number,class,row_number()over(partition by class order by number) Placement
FROM MyTable
```

If you are using any older version of DB which does not support **row_number()over()** then you can achieve it through sub query:

```
select *,(select count(*) from rowNumberForOldDB where class=t.class and 
       number<t.number)+1 Placement from rowNumberForOldDB t
```

Comment: `row_number()` is standard SQL.  There is really no need to list the databases that support it, but if you do, the list is much longer than that.

Comment: I do agree. Appreciate your concern. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysql, you may do this:

```
SET @num := 0;
SELECT t.*, @num := @num + 1 AS 'row_num' FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table 
    GROUP BY field_a 
    ORDER BY field_b
) t
```